# Why does my 1.5 years old credit card not appear on my credit report?

Tags: canada, credit-score

I tried to buy my credit score on Equifax but it wouldn't let me buy it but told me I can purchase a report for $15 instead of the $25 one required for my rental application. So in the $15 one it was blank!! Just said I made 4 inquiries in the last 2 years and that's it!! I had got a RBC Visa last January to develop credit but it's not on the report!!  What is going on?

So I tried to buy a Transunion one it wouldn't let me buy it saying "can't verify identity".

Edit: Canadian here!

Comment: Are you sure you're trying the Canadian versions of these sites?  Experian seems to use a different experian.ca site for Canada...

Comment: @quid Tried Equifax.ca and Transunion.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though RBC may not report to Equifax, which they're not required to do.  Every creditor has the option of not reporting at all, or to report to as many or few of the major bureaus as they choose.  It seems funny that RBC wouldn't report, so my suggestion would be to make sure the information they have on file to identify you (name, DOB, etc.) is correct, because it is possible they're sending faulty data to the bureaus on you (this happens a WHOLE lot more often than you'd like to think!), so your credit info would never show up, because there's no file to match it with.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Reporting to credit agencies is optional.  Pretty much everyone does report to **a** credit agency, but they don't necessarily report to **all** credit agencies.  In Canada you have Equifax and Transunion.  Most likely your credit card company is reporting only to Transunion and not Equifax.  This means if someone pulls your credit and they pull Equifax, it will seem like you have no credit history.  I've had a similar problem--my credit score under one agency is much higher than under another because they have different information.  There isn't a way around this.  Basically you need to open a number of different credit accounts to ensure that you have people reporting to both agencies.

Note that you can request a credit report for free any time as a Canadian citizen if you do it by mail.

Links for [Transunion](https://www.transunion.ca/ca/personal/creditreport/consumerdisclosure/mail_en.page) and [Equifax](https://help-en.equifax.ca/app/answers/detail/a_id/297/noIntercept/1).

These are "soft" inquiries and are not recorded as part of your credit score.

You can also pay about $15 to get your instant credit report, which is what it seems like you did, or a little more to get your report and score.  However, these instant reports are not always that great at verifying your identity.  I've had this problem as well.  The solution is to order it by mail.

Answer (score -2):

You might have fallen for cheat companies that sell you a minimum of information.

You should always use 'www.annualcreditreport.com' first; it is a government-triggered site and allows you to get all three major credit reports completely, and *for free* (once per year). Make sure to not accidentally buy any 'upgrades' they offer there, but it works and you can see all details they have about you (except the ratings they give you).

Comment: Also worth noting that Credit Karma has a free service that pulls information from the credit reporting agencies, too.

Comment: annualcreditreport.com was created at the demand of the *United States* government for the use of US consumers.  Based on the tags, the OP is Canadian, and their account is at RBC (Royal Bank of Canda), a Canadian bank.  I wouldn't think annualcreditreport.com would help them.  For one thing, you need a US Social Security number to get started on that site.